# PyQt/PySide: Search Bar to Search Button

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I've a program that generates button based on number of items from a json file. There's totals of 100+ items generating 100+ buttons. Scrolling through it one by one using `QScrollArea` are a waste of time. That's why I wanted to make some Search bar to search for a button that has similar/exact name to the one I search: [Programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DraV.png)

The button only have icons, not a button name. I'm not sure what's the best way on how to approach this. This is the only idea I could get:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QComboBox, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QCompleter, QPushButton, QWidget
from itertools import product

buttons = {}

def templates():
    global layouts
    layouts = QVBoxLayout()
    layouts.addWidget(buttons[combo.currentText()][0])
    main_layout.addLayout(layouts)
    main_widget.show()

main_app = QApplication([])
main_widget = QWidget()
main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
layouts = QVBoxLayout()

for _ in range(4):
    btn = QPushButton(str(_))
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda *args, texti=btn.text(): print(texti))
    buttons[str(_)] = [btn]
    layouts.addWidget(btn)

combo = QComboBox()
combo.addItems(list(buttons))
combo.setEditable(True)
combo.setInsertPolicy(QComboBox.NoInsert)
combo.completer().setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
combo.editTextChanged.connect(templates)
main_layout.addWidget(combo)
main_layout.addLayout(layouts)

main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
main_widget.show()
main_app.exec()
```

I'm using a `buttons = {}` dictionary to keep a reference to that button. The reason behind this:

- 1. Since I couldn't get the buttons through `btn.text()`, I can still use the key from the dictionary.
- 2. I can't create a custom variable from string to define the button, unless using `exec()`.

I'm trying to get this same functionality: [PyQt Icon Search Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mI8f--WAC3I). The buttons are nested using layout, so reaching the items must iterate over the layout first. Using String Model only take care of list of string, the idea is the same as I previously demonstrated, so I tends to avoid that.

I'm looking for a specific Qt Module that can finds occurences to `QPushButton` in a Widget or multiple Layouts. More or so, many tutorials only related to SQL, this is limiting amount of search for a reference.

Comment: Please note that your question is broad and asking for suggestions that would result in opinion based answers is considered off topic. That said, using a basic widget-based scroll area for this is probably not a good idea to begin with, especially for such a big element count. A better solution would be to use a QListView (with an `IconMode` view or `LeftToRight` flow with the `wrapping` property set to True), with a model for the items that can be eventually filtered using a proxy model. Then, use a custom delegate to display items as you with.

Comment: Sorry, I should've describing it better. I've been revise the thread into more specific case  @musicamante

Comment: Sorry but that update doesn't change that much. In any case, I think you're thinking the problem in the wrong way: instead of continuously adding items, you should *hide* those that don't match the criteria. Also note that QObjects support custom properties: use `obj.setProperty('someproperty', value)` to set it, and `obj.property('someproperty')` to get it. I still think that using a scroll area for this is not a good idea, especially considering the amount of items you're going to have. An item view with a model is certainly faster and more flexible.

Comment: That's a good tip, I've implementing the QListView alongside the Combobox, so the generated button can still remain. Thank you @musicamante